# IP addresses and how to find them?

Tags: windows

i'm trying to find the IP address of a PC but when i use the CMD it shows odd stuff instead of the IP like fe80:2de0 and it go's on but i don't want to reveal any info of this PC's IP address someone plz help

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with an Apple product? Are you asking how to find an IP address on a Mac? Because you stated you're looking for the address of a PC, and you mentioned CMD (which is the Windows Command Prompt, not the Mac Terminal)

Comment: Perhaps he or she is using Bootcamp (or a virtual machine)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about Apple products as defined in the FAQ

Comment: @aglasser, the procedure to check an IP address is the same on a Windows virtual machine as it is on a normal Windows PC

Comment: I understand that, Chris. I answered because they may be running Windows on Apple hardware.

Answer (score 2):

IP addresses come in two major flavors, IPv4 and IPv6.

There can be multiple ipv6 addresses per interface.  The fe80:... is a link-local address for ipv6.

Your ipv4 addresses are listed separately.  For example 192.168.10.10 ....

Answer (score 0):

If Windows is set to use both IPv6 and IPv4, `ipconfig` will output both addresses.

IPv6 has the format that you mentioned.

IPv4, however, is probably what you are looking for. This is an `x.x.x.x` formatted address.

When running `ipconfig`, notice the lines containing "IPv6 Address" and "IPv4 Address". Both will be listed.

[image: ipconfig]

Comment: Downvoted. Instead of answering a question that clearly has absolutely nothing to do with an Apple product, you should have flagged the question as "**Blatantly off-topic** (this question has nothing to do with Apple hardware or software)"

Comment: The user may be accustomed to Mac OS X and not understand how to find his or her IPv4 address from inside of Windows (Bootcamp or a virtual machine). I understand that the question has nothing to do specifically with an Apple product, but I figured I would help them out and answer their question regardless.

Comment: The question is also an extremely simple one that could have been solved after spending a grand total of 5 minutes on Google (less time, I think, than it took the OP to even write this question). It clearly shows a lack of research.